# Check if 2 floating point numbers are almost equal - Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to check if all the numbers in an array are almost equal to a particular number. 
I am using the Numpy.testing module on python
Eg:

`array = [0.019968,0.020010,0.019975,0.019986,0.020021 ]`
`number = 0.02`

I need the answer to be true for all the cases.

This is what I tried but i always get a failure

`numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(array[1], 0.02)`
`numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal_nulp(array[1],0.02)`

Are there any other absolute and relative threshold parameter that i will need to set.

Comment: Have you consulted the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal.html)?

Answer (score 2):

you have to setup decimal.

```
numpy.testing.assert_array_almost_equal(array[1], 0.02, decimal=2)
```

default value of decimal is 6 and the sample data you provide exceeds the gap.

decimal can work up to 5 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `assert_allclose(actual, desired)` too.

```py
from numpy.testing import assert_allclose
```

To use *relative* tolerance:

```py
assert_allclose(array, np.full_like(array, number), rtol=1e-2)
```

To use *absolute* tolerance:

```py
assert_allclose(array, np.full_like(array, number), atol=1e-4)
```